What is the role of the Medic class from Path of War?
I believe that the Medic class is trying to fulfill the role of an in combat non-magical healer, but I can’t help but think it was intended for more. As a secondary Initiator, it has 7 levels of maneuvers to choose from, and fulfill more roles than a simple healer. So what is intended for? It has the Golden Lion discipline, and the option to get roaring mouse, so is it a buffer? It has the option to gain Leaden Hyena, and has Steel Serpent, so is it a debuffer? It has Broken Blade, is it meant to be a striker? I’m confused about what it was intended to do.

So, I didn't write the medic, but I did work with the fellow who did, and provided a good amount of feedback on it. Medic is primarily a combat non-magical healer, as you noted. Any medic will fulfill that role. Your choice of disciplines helps you round out a secondary role. I don't know what roaring mouse or leaden hyena are, but golden lion lets you play as more of a dnd 4e warlord, mixing buffs into your heals, while steel serpent lets you play into more pressure point style, disabling enemies while patching up allies. And broken blade lets you just be someone who makes health bars go up and down. Generally speaking, only being able to do one thing is poor class design, so routes are left open for players to expand on the core function of the class.

I use Library of Metzofitz to track homebrew content, and those are alternative disciplines from other publishers. I also have a question about the ability contour; What offensive ability score is the Medic designed to have, or is it meant to be variable?

Well, do remember that stuff made by other publishers wouldn't reflect any intent by the original author.
It's been years since I actually looked at the mechanics in PoW, but I believe most classes were deliberately left open to using Strength or Dexterity

Yes, I do remember that. I just think they are well built disciplines.
